# erreur of aspectRatio on flutter

Tags: flutter

hello I tried to make a geofencing responsive, I have a stack of google map url and  a circle. this code is OK :

```
                                new Card(
                                  elevation: 2.0,
                                  child: new Stack(
                                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[

                                      new Container(
                                        child: new Image.network(staticMapUri.toString()),
                                      ),
                                      new Container(
                                        alignment: new FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                          color: Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.5),
                                        ),
                                        child:
                                        new AspectRatio(
                                          aspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.longestSide/GPS2,
                                          child :
                                          FractionalTranslation(
                                            translation: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                                            child: new Container(
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      new Container(
                                        //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10.0),
                                        margin: new EdgeInsets.all(140.0),
                                        child : Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.white, size: 25.0),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
```

But I search to replace GPS2 to be dynamics with slider value so here is the code :

---

```
                                       new Slider(
                                        value: valperimetre,
                                        onChanged: (double e) => change(e),
                                        activeColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                                        inactiveColor :Colors.grey,
                                        divisions: 10,
                                        label: "$valperimetre""m",
                                        max : 500.0,
                                        min: 0.0,
                                      ),
```

---

```
              new Card(
                elevation: 2.0,
                child: new Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    new Container(
                      child: new Image.network(staticMapUri.toString()),
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      alignment: new FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.5),
                      ),
                      child:
                      new AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.longestSide/valperimetre,
                        child :
                        FractionalTranslation(
                          translation: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                          child: new Container(
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10.0),
                      margin: new EdgeInsets.all(140.0),
                      child : Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.white, size: 25.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

but currently I have this error :" if I rebuild the app normaly : failed assertion:line 399 pos 15:'aspectRatio.isFinite': is not true."
If I replace valperimetre by 100.0, after rebuild app, and after I replace 100.0 by valperimetre and I hotreload it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Putting this condition check inside your code.

```
//your code here
 child:(valperimetre == 0.0 || valperimetre == null) ? 
        Container()
       :new AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.longestSide/valperimetre,
//your code here
```